# Custom Map using iPhone MapKit

Tags: iphone, google-maps, mapkit

I am attempting to use MapKit to create a custom map (similar to this concept http://mapwow.com/) using an image instead of the google maps image. This is so we can include the gps functionality and the pins functionality. I have looked in the documentation and there does not appear to be a standard way of doing it. Is there a way to do this using MapKit or has someone found a way to achieve something similar?

Comment: You whould maybe refer to that post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534691/how-to-geolocalize-on-custom-maps-iphone-and-android/6534929#6534929](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534691/how-to-geolocalize-on-custom-maps-iphone-and-android/6534929#6534929)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't currently use anything other than the Google Maps with MapKit.

Dmytro has already pointed to useful links that provide alternatives, particularly the [route-me library](http://code.google.com/p/route-me/), but there's also the [CloudMade API](http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/iphone-api) which provides another alternative.

If you want to roll your own, you may find the [CATiledLayer](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) class helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [route-me](http://code.google.com/p/route-me/) project. It allows developer to use custom map sources such as [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/), [CloudMade](http://maps.cloudmade.com/) etc and supports pins. 
BTW CloudMade has [a map style edito](http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/style-editor)r which might be useful for you