# How can i make custom map for showing user current location in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, android-mapview

i want to show my current location on custom map.The custom map is of my locality....so,please help me how can i use custom map in place of google map???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Map using iPhone MapKit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709786/custom-map-using-iphone-mapkit)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with offline maps is not the "map" but all the stuff you need to build to georeference your map.
Think only at a map zoom.
There are many good open source libraries/SDK to manage offline maps.

--EDIT--

It seems that the free code I found was removed.
As soon as I will find a new available one I will update this comment