# ios custom maps, geolocation, mapping and more

Tags: ios, geolocation, maps

The next image was taken from www.Trimaps.com

[image: Mapping of an area from Google Maps to a custom image]

(I hope it's allowed to use images here, if not, please tell me and i'll remove it immediately).

These images explain perfectly what i'm trying to accomplish.

I have all the data one would need:

1. Latitude/Longitude (in decimal values) of 4 corners of the desired area (from Google Maps).
2. A beautiful custom image of a mountain (similar to the right image).

All i need is the math. I've tried all the formula's, scaling/ transfomations, you name it.

I'm sure it's possible as it depends on pure MATH, relatively simple math equations.

www.Trimaps.com currently wants 300$ from using their code.
With all deu respect, it's a little expensive for me...

Does anyone knows about open source or have achieved this by himself?

UPDATE: BTW, I'm not asking for code to copy & paste. I know how to code.

I'm asking about the procedure, the logic behind, formulas.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated :)

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That also depends on complexity you may afford.
For example that would be better to split big map image to small tiles and load them on demand.

You could use UIScrollView anyway, using tiles or not. I'll be short with a single huge-image solution (not sure if it will be ok to use big image like this). You need to choose degree-for-km ratio calculation equation, you may find a lot in wikipedia: [Latitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude) or search `km per degree latitude` or like this.
When you know how many km is in one degree latitude and one degree longitude you may use this information along with zoom level of scrollView. So now you need to get how many km is in one point according to the zoom level of scrollView. You may get the ratio easily as far as you know geographical rectangle coordinates, scrollView's frame and scrollView's content state.

With all that info you may transform location coordinates to view points and vice versa. So you may even put a location pin or something.

Also check this: http://mapbox.com/mobile/ and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2709786/1032151).

**UPDATE:**
At first, man, that's really unpleasant to see my answer to be unaccepted, but anyway, I'll add some info. Next time I'm not going to bother.
Check UIScrollView's [contentOffset and contentSize](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) properties. That means you can manage zoom level by yourself using some combination of `contentSize` and `contentView's frame`. I mean you may resize for example an UIImageView and position it's visible frame with UIScrollView's contentOffset.

Comment: Hello M!
A couple of things.
First, the area i'm mapping is small, less then 2x2 km. I've read about the "km per degree", was helpful!

Second, i'm using a scrollView. can you please explain more about the Zoom level of it, and how may i use it for calculation? THIS IS KEY POINT for me! this is where i'm really stuck...i'm trying to find that ratio (or scale factor...what ever it is) between the two NON-SIMILAR rectangles. Moreover, after i've found 'X' km per degree, what is the formula for calculating 1 km per scrollView point according to the zoom level? THANKS MATE!

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to do so. Not intentionally anyway. Thanks for your time and great answer!