# Where do I start to make a Golf Course GPS App

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make a golf GPS app for my local golf course. I want it to show from tee box to green and have distances to front middle and back of green and also to hazards such as water and sand traps. I want to make it so it only show images of each hole similar to the sonocaddie app. I am unsure how to start to build this app and I am hoping someone here has made one before and lead me on the right path. I have been searching for a long tin but I cannot find any information. If you have any information for me please help. Thank you.

Comment: StackOverflow is a programming FAQ. We have specific, focused questions with specific answers. We do not have (long) discussions here. We are not a forum. Please narrow your question down to something specific.

Comment: The question is specific. I'm just asking where do I start to make this kind of app. I've seen plenty of questions asking similar questions which have answers so I thought it would be ok to ask here.

Comment: Maybe specific is the wrong term. Maybe atomic would be a better term. Your question can easily be broken down into dozens if not hundreds or thousands of subquestions. Most of those questions have already been answered on this very website. If you have other atomic questions to ask which haven't already been asked/answered, feel free to ask those.

Comment: That's the whole point of the question. The OP doesn't know what parts this question needs to be broken down into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base of this app would be the map, the problem I see here is to combine your live geo-localization with a custom view/map.

I found [something that might be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075911/ios-custom-maps-geolocation-mapping-and-more).

As the answer suggets, [MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com/mobile/) would be a good option to start with.

Thats all what I can help with, remember here you need to ask specific programming questions to be specific answered.

Hope it helps.